# Generic Dictionary as ref method param

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something like this

```
public void GetData(ref Dictionary<T,V> dataDictionary)
{


}
```

Where T can be GUID, string, or int and V is custom user or item object.

Comment: Well, you can't restrict T to only be Guid, string or int - but other than that it should work. It would help if you'd post an actual question.

Comment: Jon, i do not want to restrict it to GUID, string, int but just mentioned those types as an example. BTW, big fan of your blog

Comment: Glad you like the blog :) But what's the actual question here? I agree with Robert - you almost certainly don't really want to be using ref.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want the ability to change the callers reference? Why isn't

```
public Dictionary<T,V> GetData<T,V>()
```

good enough?

In your ref-based world:

```
public void GetData<T,V>(ref Dictionary<T,V> dictionary)
```

---

EDIT: Not that I in any way condone the following, but ...

If you need to care about the different types T can be, you can create generic overrides the same way you can create any override method.

```
// client code
Dictionary<int, object> x = null;
GetData(ref x);

Dictionary<string, Guid> y = null;
GetData(ref y);
```

generic overrides:

```
public void GetData<V>(ref Dictionary<int, V> dictionary)
{
    dictionary = new Dictionary<int,V>(); // reassign reference.
}
public void GetData<V>(ref Dictionary<string, V> dictionary) { ... }
public void GetData<V>(ref Dictionary<Guid, V> dictionary) { ... }
```

While semantically the same, the following overrides are not possible with return values because of ambiguity.

```
public Dictionary<int, T> ReturnData<T>() { ... }
public Dictionary<string, T> ReturnData<T>() { ... }
```

> error CS0111: Type 'Testing' already defines a member called 'ReturnData' with the same parameter types

You can get around the ambiguity by passing the object in and out, but that's equally horrid to look at:

```
public Dictionary<int, T> ReturnData<T>(Dictionary<int, T> self) { ... }
public Dictionary<string, T> ReturnData<T>(Dictionary<string, T> self) { ... }
```

Comment: now that you mention it, it may be a bad idea using the ref keyword. guess i should not work on someone else's code late evenings

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?  Any additional info would be helpful.

```
public void GetData<T, V>(ref Dictionary<T, V> dataDictionary) {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string) || typeof(T) == typeof(int) || typeof(T) == typeof(Guid)) {
       ...
    } else {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the objective here? You mention that `string`/`Guid` etc were just examples, so I don't think we need to focus on those...

If you simply want to be able to manipulate the dictionary contents, then "done" - that already works. since `Dictionary<,>` is a reference-type, the caller will already see any changes you make. You can remove the `ref` too...

```
public void GetData(Dictionary<T,V> dataDictionary) // or IDictionary<T,V>
{
    T key = GetSomeKey();
    V value = dataDictionary[key]; // query
    dataDictionary.Remove(key); // mutate
}
```